# What does "push a controller onto another controller" mean?

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

I have a `FirstViewController` which is my **root navigation controller**. I have a compose button and I want to display the TTMessage Composer **modally** on click. This works fine.

The problem is that there is no navigation bar to cancel the composer, so I have to add one.

This how it looks like without a navigation bar by just presenting the message composer (**TTMessageController**) modally.

[image]

[I found this from three20 google group:](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/6b72cad92eb1daa4)

> Before you present the message
>   controller, you have to create a
>   navigation controller, push the
>   message controller onto it, and then
>   present the navigation controller
>   modally.

It seems like the solution for my problem but I do not understand it. Can anyone explain it with a little bit of code? I now the navigation controller from the objects panel and I can drag it on my nib files but what does it mean in this case? And what means "push"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a navigation controller using an extant view controller, you can use initWithRootViewController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController =
   [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTTMessageComposer];
```

If you're just using the navigation bar for "decoration", though (i.e. you wont actually navigate from the message view), you can just add a navigation bar directly to the TTMessageComposer's view.

To learn about view controllers and navigation, read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1).

Comment: If I do it like you describe it TTMessageController even autogenerates the bar items for me :) thanks a lot!